# .jar dependencies when importing facebook sample projects

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook, jar

Im trying to import the sample facebook sdk projects into eclipse, and am getting this error on all the projects except for Hackbook.

```
Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
Versions found are:
Path: C:\Program Files\facebook-android-sdk-3.0.2\facebook\libs\android-support-v4.jar 
Length: 349252
SHA-1: 612846c9857077a039b533718f72db3bc041d389
Path: C:\Program Files\facebook-android-sdk-3.0.2\libs\android-support-v4.jar
Length: 556198
SHA-1: 4a6be13368bb64c5a0b0460632d228a1a915f58f
Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
```

Is there anyway I can delete one of these from the build path? I've tried Build Path>Configure Build Path to delete the second jar file, but it reappears after I close the window.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply copy one (for example C:\Program Files\facebook-android-sdk-3.0.2\facebook\libs\android-support-v4.jar) replacing the other (C:\Program Files\facebook-android-sdk-3.0.2\libs\android-support-v4.jar) so you have the same version of the library